# why does `getBoundingClientRect` give me an unexpected result

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this piece of code

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.container').getBoundingClientRect())
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: fit-content;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: coral;
  border: 20px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container"></div>
</main>
```

I'm trying to get the bounding rect of the `.container` I expect to get `200px` for both the width and height and values bigger than `8px` for the x, y, top, and left.

the blue box is the `.container` it has a width and height of `200px` and its x and y from the top left of the viewport should be much greater than `8px`.

as I understand it the bounding rect should

> returns a `DOMRect` providing information about the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

the bounding rect I get looks like this

```
{
  bottom: 8,
  height: 0,
  left: 8,
  right: 950,
  top: 8,
  width: 942,
  x: 8,
  y: 8
}
```

so why am I getting `8px` for the x and why when it's clearly not `8px` as the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAXi1.png) shows.

Is there something I'm missing about how the `getClientBoundingRect` function works?

Comment: It's showing the `x` and `y` after the containing block's positioning and padding.

Comment: @Rojo I'm not sure what you mean. can you elaborate a little more

Comment: Have you tried to run the snippet here without any scrolling? The dimensions and the x and y I am getting are totally different from what you have quoted.

Comment: @MrBrN197 nevermind, that's for something else. Also, the snippet is not giving me `x: 8` and `y: 8`.

Comment: Ohh... I am looking through the edits and I see where it went wrong. Put your script tag after the `style` tag and everything should work fine.

Comment: @Rojo yes I've also noticed the snippet isn't giving the wrong result. I've just checked it on codepen and it seems to be working there. but it doesn't work on my installed Firefox, Chrome, Brave and Microsoft Edge. can you try it on your local browser.

Comment: The script is running before the styles are applied. Before all styling, the elements are at `x: 8, y: 8`

Comment: @Rojo thanks so much. what a silly mistake. I was actually thinking something was wrong with my entire computer. I guess that didn't matter in code pen and the snippets cause it decides when it will run the specific section. Thank you again